# MVC Entity Framework Select isnull field

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am developing and `MVC` with `Entity Framework`. I am a Select like this.

```html
 IEnumerable<UploadSearch> viewModel = (from uploads in _db.Uploads
            select new UploadSearch
                                      {
                                          Positives = uploads.Positives,
                                      });
```

The Select Works fine. There is no need to explain too match what it does.

What I need to do, is to retrieve zero (0), when a field like `uploads.Positives` is null

Something like this

> Select isnull(Positives,0)

How can I do it?

Thanks..

Comment: [?? Operator (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making an assumption here...  If you want `0` then what you're talking about is an `int?` (or `Nullable<int>`), right?

Given that, you can check if it has a value in a conditional operation.  Something like:

```
select new UploadSearch
{
    Positives = uploads.Positives.HasValue ? uploads.Positives : 0
}
```

Or, if the LINQ provider doesn't like `.HasValue` or something of that nature (or you're not using a `Nullable<T>` for some reason) then you can also check for `null` explicitly:

```
select new UploadSearch
{
    Positives = uploads.Positives == null ? 0 : uploads.Positives
}
```

If the LINQ provider supports the `??` operator, you can even shorten it to something like this:

```
select new UploadSearch
{
    Positives = uploads.Positives ?? 0
}
```